# Sum multiple numbers in a cell

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that I am working on but some of the cells contain "|" in between that is why I can't sum the values. I tried many ways but could not come up with a solution. Basically, my output should be like column F below.

```
E:             F:
25.00|0.00     25
0              0
10.00          0
3.00|13.00     16
3.00           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FILTERXML with SUM, depending on the version of Excel you have:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><n>" & SUBSTITUTE(E1, "|", "</n><n>") & "</n></t>", "//n"))
```

You can also create a UDF with VBA, using EVALUATE like this:

```
Function sumIt(raw)
    
    sumIt = Application.Evaluate(Replace(raw, "|", "+"))
    
End Function
```

or SPLIT, like this:

```
Function sumIt(raw)
    
    arr = Split(raw, "|")
    For Each a In arr
        sumIt = sumIt + CDec(a)
        Next
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `FilterXML()` then `SUM()`. Try-

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(E1,"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, also can we use this filterxml in Google sheets? Can it work in GS as well?

Comment: @t.cvmk `FILTERXML()` is not available to google-sheet but GS have `SPLIT()` equivalent formula.

Answer (score -1):

Try solutions given [here], these are for `comma` but should be working for `|` as well (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3959-excel-sum-numbers-with-commas.html)